# Should I report a problem after my laptop has shut down due to lack of power?

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, bug-reporting

Whenever my laptop shuts down due to lack of power (running out of battery or being unplugged from the mains) I am asked whether I should report a problem, as if the system had crashed.

My question is whether reporting that as a problem actually helps software developers or only makes them waste time.

Answer (score 0):

You should report it!

Even if it's waste of time as you say. But it may has an error from back-of-the-scene and maybe it can help.

Comment: Why do you think "it may be an error from back-of-the-scene" if, for example, I have just by mistake unplugged my laptop when no battery is in?